# the blue port on the sound card

Tags: sound-card

my microphone sometimes works sometimes not,

i read that the blue port is used as an input for audio devices,

can this blue port be used for voice input using mic?

and   "without the use of mic?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Line In port has different audio characteristics from the Mic In port (such as no mic preamp), and isn't really suitable for use with a microphone.